# Powershell commands/scripts not actually running

Tags: powershell, emscripten

I am trying to install Emscripten on my computer, and I have run into trouble getting Emscripten actually installed. 
I am using the same commands as can be found on the [project webpage](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html), but when I try to run

```
emsdk install latest
```

Powershell (which is what I am using, but the basic command prompt is behaving the same way) doesn't do anything at all - it just returns without installing anything.

For reference, I have installed Emscripten on this same computer before, but decided to try and do a fresh install of Emscripten after running `emsdk activate latest` decided to "stop working" as well (whereas it worked just fine last week) - running the command, Powershell simply returned without actually *doing* anything.

Any ideas on what to check to see why these commands don't seem to run?

Comment: Are you running powershell/cmd as admin?

Comment: The same thing occurs if I run it as an admin or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it. When running the install command in Powershell ISE, it threw the error "Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkID=2082640"
despite me having Python installed. Changing the order of my PATH variables to set my Python install directory above the Winapps directory solved the issue with running the install command.